# I too get the " Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org."

Tags: schema.org, microdata

My data is spread all over so I can't keep this format :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">
    <p itemprop="description">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
             <span itemprop="price">      
    </div>
</div>
```

Like you see in the code below the first thing on the page is the category path which has to be inside Offer schema than I have the image and the title which belong to Product than I have eligibleQuantity that again belongs to the Offer and so on....
So I added the :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
```

In the beginning of the page and closed it at the end and than whenever I had an element that does not belong to the product schema like "eligibleQuantity" for example I would do this:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      {L_901}: <span itemprop="eligibleQuantity">{QTY}</span><br />
      </div>
```

The problem is I don't know if this is the correct way to do it and can't figure another way. I also get the "Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org."
Here is a link to the page :

https://www.pchounds.com/item.php?id=82627#.UTi7kRz_mSp

and below is some code from the page so you can have an idea what I did. Thank you.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="breadcrumb"> {L_041}:<span itemprop="category"> {TOPCATSPATH}</span> </div>

...........................................................................................
!-- IF B_HASIMAGE -->
<div class="span3" style="text-align:center"> <img class="img-polaroid" itemprop="image"
   src="{SITEURL}getthumb.php?w={THUMBWIDTH}&fromfile={PIC_URL}" border="0" alt="title" align="center"><br>
<h1 itemprop="name" style="line-height:24px;">{TITLE}</h1>...........................................................................................
<!-- IF QTY gt 1 -->
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  {L_901}: <span itemprop="eligibleQuantity">{QTY}</span><br />
  </div>
  <!-- ENDIF -->
  <!-- IF B_HASENDED -->
  {L_904}<br />
  <!-- ENDIF -->  
  <!-- IF ITEM_CONDITION -->
   <b> {L_1036}:</b> <span itemprop="itemCondition">{ITEM_CONDITION}</span><br /> 
    <!-- ENDIF -->  
   <!-- IF ITEM_MANUFACTURER --> 
  <b> {L_1037}:</b> <span itemprop="manufacturer">{ITEM_MANUFACTURER}</span><br />                      
  <!-- ENDIF -->
  <!-- IF ITEM_MODEL -->
  <b> {L_1038}:</b> <span itemprop="mpn">{ITEM_MODEL}</span><br />
  <!-- ENDIF -->
  <!-- IF ITEM_COLOUR -->
  <b> {L_1039}:</b> <span itemprop="color">{ITEM_COLOUR}</span><br />                                                
  <!-- ENDIF -->
  <!-- IF ITEM_YEAR -->
  <b> {L_1040}:</b> {ITEM_YEAR}<br />
  <!-- ENDIF -->  
   </small>
```

Answer (score 0):

**offer** must have a price, `<span itemprop="price">` must be followed by the value of the price but is not and there are multiple Offers when there should just be one. Looking at the current test results from Google's structured data testing tool there are 5 errors, each states *the price is missing*.

The problem seems to be that each part of the offer has a separate `http://schema.org/Offer' at the start - so it is expecting 5 prices, one for each of the 5 offers.

What you need to do is declare `http://schema.org/Offer' **once**, for example an extra`` which remains open until all offer values are added.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
 <div class="breadcrumb"> Item category:<span itemprop="category"> <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/browse.php?id=1">All</a> > <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/browse.php?id=313">Electronics</a> > <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/browse.php?id=857">Audio</a> > <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/browse.php?id=879">Audio Components</a> > <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/browse.php?id=899">Speakers</a></span>    
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="span3" style="text-align:center"> <img class="img-polaroid" itemprop="image" src="https://www.pchounds.com/getthumb.php?w=120&fromfile=uploaded/82627/82627.jpg" border="0" alt="title" align="center"><br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span5">
 <h1 itemprop="name" style="line-height:24px;">Creative Labs Speaker GigaWorks T20 Series II Systems 2.0 EPS complian</h1>
 <div><!-- schema.org/Offer removed -->
  <em>
  <p><small>Buy Now:    
  <span itemprop="price"><b>108.91</b> <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/converter.php?AMOUNT=108.91" alt="converter" class="new-window">USD</a></span></small></p> 
  </em> 
 </div>

<div class="span5">
<h1 itemprop="name" style="line-height:24px;">Creative Labs Speaker GigaWorks T20 Series II Systems 2.0 EPS complian</h1>
 <div> <!-- removed http://schema.org/Offer -->
 <em>
 <p><small>Buy Now:    
 <span itemprop="price"><b>108.91</b> <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/converter.php?AMOUNT=108.91" alt="converter" class="new-window">USD</a></span></small></p> 
 </em> 
 </div>
 Shipping fee: <b>8.00</b> <a href="https://www.pchounds.com/converter.php?AMOUNT=8.00" alt="converter" class="new-window">USD</a><br />
 <small>Ends within:
 <span id="ending_counter"><span class="errfont">closed</span></span><br />
 <p> Seller location: United States<br />
  <div> <!-- removed http://schema.org/Offer -->
  <b>Payment methods:</b><span itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod"> PayPal</span> </p>
 </div>
  </small>

... 

</div>
```