# Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org

Tags: microdata

I take a warning like that: "Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org." when Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" style="display: none;">
        <img itemprop="image" runat="server" id="listImage" src="" />
        <span itemprop="name" runat="server" id="listName"></span>
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
              <span itemprop="ratingValue" runat="server" id="rValue"></span>out of <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> based on 
              <span itemprop="ratingCount" runat="server" id="allRating"></span>user ratings
        </div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
               <span itemprop="lowPrice" runat="server" id="lowPrice"></span>to <span itemprop="highPrice" runat="server" id="highPrice"></span>
               <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="TRY" />
        </div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
               <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="firstHotel"></a>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
               <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="secondHotel"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

what is the problem?
thank u

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15276480/1591669

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank u.

I changed

```
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
           <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="firstHotel"></a>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
           <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="secondHotel"></a>
    </div>
```

with

```
     <div>
     <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="firstHotel"></a>
     <a itemprop="url" href="" runat="server" id="secondHotel"></a>
     </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, because i have a lot of itemprops for Offer.

Answer (score 0):

Google requires certain properties to be present to possibly trigger rich snippets. You ought to check the Google documentation here:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue with the price value. It needs to have 2 decimal precision.

WRONG:

```
<meta content="4.5" itemprop="price"></meta>
```

RIGHT:

```
<meta content="4.50" itemprop="price"></meta>
```